# Remove a column from a list of columns returned from a Big Query python API call

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to remove a column from a list of columns returned from a Big Query query.

I'm using the python Big Query API and returning a list of columns using a sql statement:

```
SELECT column_name FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Then perform a list on the returned result:

```
bq_schema_target = list(query_job.result())
```

`print(bq_schema_target)`

returns--->

```
[Row(('crownumber',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('cstring1',), {'column_name': 0})]
```

The approach I'm trying is:

`Column = 'cstring1'`

```
if Column in bq_schema_target :
    bq_schema_target.remove(Column)
```

This approach is not finding my Column in the list

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to delete a specific element from your columns list which is the result of your query.

The approach you are trying, using the [remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method, is not working because  ***list(query_job.result())*** returns a list of tuples. Thus, in order to access a particular element inside it, it is necessary to: *loop through the list, ignore the unwanted element, append the results to a new list*. I have created two approaches for your case. Also, with the solutions below I have used a public dataset,*census_bureau_usa*, for testing the code.

***First, partially using your code:***

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

list_of_columns=[]

query = """
    SELECT
     column_name
    FROM
     `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
     table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
"""

query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request
query
bq_schema_target = list(query_job.result())

for row in bq_schema_target:
    if row[0] != "geo_id":
        list_of_columns.append(row)
    
print("Initial list of columns:\n{}".format(bq_schema_target))
print("\n\n")
print("Final list of columns:\n{}".format(list_of_columns))
```

And the output,

```
    Initial list of columns:
    [Row(('geo_id',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('zipcode',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('population',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('minimum_age',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('maximum_age',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('gender',), {'column_name': 0})]
    
    Final list of columns:
    [Row(('zipcode',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('population',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('minimum_age',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('maximum_age',), {'column_name': 0}), Row(('gender',), {'column_name': 0})]
```

Notice that the column named `geo_id` is not included in the final list `list_of_columns`.

***Second, within this approach the list method is not used, instead the query results are accessed directly and only the desired columns are appended to the final list of columns. As follows,***

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

list_of_columns=[]

query = """
    SELECT
     column_name
    FROM
     `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
     table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
"""

query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request

for row in query_job:
    if row[0] != "geo_id":
        list_of_columns.append(row[0])
        #print(row[0])
        
#print("Initial list of columns:\n{}".format(bq_schema_target))
#print("\n\n")
print("Final list of columns:\n{}".format(list_of_columns))
```

And the output,

```
Final list of columns:
['zipcode', 'population', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender']
```

Once again, the column `geo_id` is not in the final output.

Comment: @BSpinoza, I am glad to know it helped. I would appreciate if you could also accept the answer.